# Rails - AssociationTypeMismatch error with associating a model with multiple instances of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Accounts and CreditRecords. An account can have many credit records that belong to it. However, accounts can also trade credit records to other accounts, and I want to keep track of who the current account owner is, and who the original owner is.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :credit_records

class CreditRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :original_owner_id, :class_name => "Account"
belongs_to :account_id, :class_name => "Account"
```

When I try to set a CreditRecord.account_id to, say, 1, it updates fine. But if I try to set CreditRecord.original_owner_id to 3, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Account(#70154465182260) expected, got Fixnum(#70154423875840)
```

Both account_id and original_owner_id are set to be integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

original_account_id is expecting an account object. you cannot set an id.

```
credit_record.original_owner = account
credit_record.account = account
```

or

```
credit_record.account_id = account.id
```

Please rename your association to the following

```
class CreditRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :original_owner, :foreign_key => "account_id", :class_name => "Account"
belongs_to :account
```

Comment: Ok. Just tried that, and now I've got this: "NameError: undefined local variable or method `foreign_key' for #<Class:0x007fb9b4e6d118>"

Comment: Sorry for that. modified my answer. It should be a symbol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to name your association `account_id` instead of just `account` in your `CreditRecord` class.  The problem with this approach is when you have/will have nested resources like the following in your routes:

```
resources :accounts do 
  resources :credit_records
end
```

you will get a URL pattern as `/accounts/:account_id/credit_records/:id/...`, and your params hash will have `account_id` parameter in it.

Suggest updating your associations as follows as suggested by @vimsha in his answer.

```
class CreditRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :original_owner, :class_name => Account, :foreign_key => 'account_id'
  belongs_to :account, :class_name => Account
end
```

This will allow you to assign account's id attribute through credit record object like:

```
# Set account's id
credit_record.account.id = 1

# Set original_owner's id
credit_record.original_owner.id = 2
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the explanation on the routing. I've changed the association to account.